# Find difference in hours passing parameter value for specific date

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my table data:

```
Fromdatetime          Todatetime             
2018-12-8 10:25 AM 2018-12-8  16:25 PM
2018-12-8 16:25 PM 2018-12-8  20:25 PM
2018-12-8 20:25 PM 2018-12-9  01:25 AM
2018-12-9 01:25 AM 2018-12-10 23:25 PM
```

Here is my list of parameter value:

```
2018-12-8 10:25 AM to 2018-12-9 10:25Am
2018-12-9 10:25 AM to 2018-12-10 10:25AM
```

For 1 parameter my output should be:

It should returned me 4 first row data Hours difference by substarcting fromdatetime and Todatetime
But in case of 4th row my hours should only calculate the difference of fromdatetime and Todatetime

Example result should be
Hours 
6
4
5
9

So can you please help me to write this query

Comment: From where you get 9 hours?

Comment: Select DATEDIFF(HH,FromDate,ToDate) From TEST where FromDate Between '2018-12-07 12:25:47.000' And '2018-12-08 12:25:47.000'

Comment: This is my query :
Select DATEDIFF(HH,FromDate,TODate) As Hour,* from Test Where FromDate Between '2018-12-08 10:25:47.000' And '2018-12-09 10:25:47.000'
or ToDate Between '2018-12-08 10:25:47.000' And '2018-12-09 10:25:47.000'

Select DATEDIFF(HH,FromDate,TODate) As Hour,* from Test Where FromDate Between '2018-12-09 10:25:47.000' And '2018-12-10 10:25:47.000'
or ToDate Between '2018-12-09 10:25:47.000' And '2018-12-10 10:25:47.000'

Answer (score 1):

Are you simply looking for `datediff()`?

```
select datediff(hour, Fromdatetime, Todatetime) as num_hours
```

Comment: I am sending a parameter and for my first parameter my last row should return hour as 9 because I only want the hour between my parameter value